# Erro ao utilizar o Inner Join no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, inner

Estou utilizando o `INNER JOIN` no mysql para juntar e exibir os dados.

Tabelas e inserção de dados:

```
CREATE TABLE EXPERIENCIA(
     exp_pri INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     experiencia VARCHAR(100),         
     PRIMARY KEY(exp_pri)
);

CREATE TABLE PRANCHA(
    prancha_pri INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tipo_prancha VARCHAR(15),
    tamanho_prancha VARCHAR(8),
    meio_prancha VARCHAR(2),
    litragem_prancha VARCHAR(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (prancha_pri)
);

CREATE TABLE ALTURAEPESO(
    idAltPes INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idExp INT,
    idPrancha INT,
    altura VARCHAR(4),
    peso VARCHAR(3),
    primary key (idAltPes),
    constraint fk_idExp foreign key (idExp) references EXPERIENCIA (exp_pri),
    constraint fk_idPrancha foreign key (idPrancha) references PRANCHA (prancha_pri)
 );    


INSERT INTO EXPERIENCIA VALUES (NULL, 'INICIANTE');
INSERT INTO EXPERIENCIA VALUES (NULL, 'INICIANTE');
INSERT INTO EXPERIENCIA VALUES (NULL, 'AVANÇADO');

INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (NULL, 'FUNBOARD', '8 PES', '21', '43L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (NULL, 'LONGBOARD', '8.8 PES', '20', '55L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (NULL, 'PRANCHA', ' 6 PES', '21', '45L');

INSERT INTO ALTURAEPESO VALUES (NULL, 1, 1, '1.90', '70');
INSERT INTO ALTURAEPESO VALUES (NULL, 2, 2, '1.70', '90');
INSERT INTO ALTURAEPESO VALUES (NULL, 3, 3, '1.60', '65');
```

Script:

```
SELECT EXP.experiencia,
       AEP.altura,
       AEP.peso,
       PRAN.tipo_prancha,
       PRAN.tamanho_prancha,
       PRAN.meio_prancha,
       PRAN.litragem_prancha
FROM EXPERIENCIA AS EXP
    INNER JOIN PRANCHA AS PRAN ON 
    (PRAN.prancha_pri = AEP.prancha_pri)
    INNER JOIN ALTURAEPESO AS AEP ON 
    (EXP.exp_pri = AEP.exp_pri)
```

O MySql está apresentando o seguinte erro:

`Unknown column 'AEP.prancha_pri' in 'on clause'`

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

O teu primeiro inner join refere-se a uma tabela que só é chamada no segundo inner join...

Tenta assim:

```
SELECT EXP.experiencia,
       AEP.altura,
       AEP.peso,
       PRAN.tipo_prancha,
       PRAN.tamanho_prancha,
       PRAN.meio_prancha,
       PRAN.litragem_prancha
FROM EXPERIENCIA AS EXP
    INNER JOIN ALTURAEPESO AS AEP ON 
    (EXP.exp_pri = AEP.exp_pri)
    INNER JOIN PRANCHA AS PRAN ON 
    (PRAN.prancha_pri = AEP.prancha_pri)
```

Answer (score -1):

Consegui!

```
SELECT EXP.experiencia,
       AEP.altura,
       AEP.peso,
       PRAN.tipo_prancha,
       PRAN.tamanho_prancha,
       PRAN.meio_prancha,
       PRAN.litragem_prancha
FROM EXPERIENCIA AS EXP
       INNER JOIN ALTURAEPESO AS AEP ON 
       (EXP.exp_pri = AEP.idAltPes)
       INNER JOIN PRANCHA AS PRAN ON 
       (PRAN.prancha_pri = AEP.idAltPes)
```

O problema foi a referência que eu estava dando para o `AlturaePeso - AEP`.

Estava chamando a `id` do `Experiencia` e não o dele mesmo, `AlturaePeso` rsrs.